# Is there any value in testing different versions of IE from version 9 and up

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser

I have the issue where I am trying to reduce the browser matrix for the regression testing to a more manageable size. The usage stats for IE show roughly even spread for different versions of IE. Now I am aware that all versions before IE9 need to be tested separately.

My question is are there any major differences between IE9, 10 and 11 that impact the way the content is displayed in a way that would justify testing separately in each browser.

Thanks!

Comment: yes. test each version of ie separately. not sure where you got info about not having to do them from ie9 and up, but in my experience, you'll never know until you do...or after you push live and someone tells you something is broken. i prefer the first route.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and my experience is the difference between IE9 and later is way less than any step below 9.

The main differences I've experienced is when relying on many HTML5 and CSS3 features, in that  case I would look a lot at IE9, otherwise, if time is a big issue, toggling between versions (not testing each extensively but at least run the main flows on a  somewhat regular basis) can be sufficient.

Also notice stimulating browsers using the developer mode is not always sufficient (just as an added note on the topic). Especially when simulating IE8 (from IE10) we've found many inconsistencies compared to running a real IE8 (virtual/real machine).

A way to save time compatibility testing a website is to mix browsers when doing other testing. This way you can cover some browsers without specific browser tests.

Finally make sure stakeholders are aware that supporting old browsers takes a lot of time from other relevant testing. This might not be obvious to them.